# How to properly handle simplejson errors?

Tags: python, simplejson

I've loaded json data to `api_result` variable. Now I need to extract particular fields (`name`, `surname`, `city` etc.). How should I verify if they are there?

```
api_result = json.loads(some_json_data)
if api_result.get('name'):
    # do something with name
if api_result.get('surname'):
    # do something with surname
if api_result.get('city'):
    # do something with city
```

Is it correct approach? Looks too complicated. Is there any way to get empty value if value is not found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[get()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) in Python has a default parameter, if the value is not found the default value will be retuned.

```
print dict.get("name", "<default name>")
```